# Inmobi Instream AD Request 400 Bad Request

Tags: vast, inmobi

I m trying to integrate Instream VAST ads in my App, I used inmobi,
As the Sample Mentioned [here](https://go.inmobi.net/hubfs/Publisher%20Collaterals%20(Anish)/API%203.0%20S2S%20VAST%20Integration%20Guidelines%20.pdf) for VAST ad request ,
I tried with different Parameter but nothing works, Is anybody tried Inmobi Instream Ads, has a success with It

My request

http://vast.w.inmobi.com/showad?plid=XXXXX&ua=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4437.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/91.0.831.1&ip=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX&gpid=XXXXXXXX&lmt=false&w=480&h=320&protocols=3&bundle=com.sample.bundle

with header
Content-Type & X-Forwarded-For

Comment: The doc you are referring to is from 2019 so check once whether it's the latest one or not.

Comment: I got reply from InMobi Team. VAST / Instream ads are no more active.